# Как реализовать игровое поле?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Нужно реализовать игровое поле как в судоку. Как мне лучше всего это сделать? 
С помощью встроенных средств или использовать различные фреймворки?
В какую сторону копать?:)

Comment: Делал тетрис - логическая часть игрового поля реализована как набор объектов с локальными координатами в поле например (5, 10), они привязаны к сабклассам SKSprite - визуальной части ( SpriteKit). Получилось просто отлично

Answer (score 1):

Двумерный массив или таблица. - самые простые варианты.
А можно разграничить площадь, на участки или насоздавать кучу объектов - но это не самые простые способы.
Всё зависит от вопроса, который вы решает.